# I've got an Ubuntu 15.10 running well, problem with Chrome and Netflix

Tags: 15.10, netflix

Whenever I try to view a movie in Netflix on Chrome (or Firefox), I get the install Silverlight barrier.
This used to work in 14.04, is this on Netflix side or on the OS software porting side? 
Just so that I know which way to send the bees in my bonnet.    ;)

Comment: I don't have this issue.  Is your system up to date?  I do know there was a very recent update to Chrome.

Comment: There was an answer referring to a similar problem [recommending not using the user agent](http://askubuntu.com/a/592381/283721), and several indicators that [chrome should work](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/watch-netflix-natively-linux-easy-way/) right out f the box.

Comment: I'm running 15.10, latest patches. I can't find the user agent described in that post, I'm guessing that its location has been moved since that post regarding the user agent selection was made. I'll have to play with it this weekend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Netflix on Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/how-can-i-use-netflix-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I know from experience that you can use Netflix on Ubuntu 15.10 with the google-chrome browser (not with the open source chromium!). You problem could be caused by some add-on or configuration issue. First things to try:

1. try to access Netflix with an incognito window (CTRL-SHIFT-N), this should  prevent all extensions from interfering. If this works, try to disable the extensions one by one until you find the guilty one.
2. try to access with a clean google-chrome profile, the easier way is to start with a different data dir:
   `google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/google-chrome-netflix`
   do NOT login to your google account (which would import all your preferences) and try to go to Netflix. If this works, you may either dig deeper in the preferences until you find what's wrong, or stick to a different google-chrome data directory especially for Netflix (do not put it in /tmp in this case)